# How to see questions I favourited?

Tags: support, bookmarks

How to see the questions which I favourited till now?

I tried a lot and could not find anywhere how to see this so always had to search and find what i wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15195/unterfallengrundhof) on the main site, and check the [**favorites**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15195/unterfallengrundhof?tab=favorites) tab, which is sixth from the left on the list of tabs available.