# How to customize MSE to see relevant tags only?

Tags: support

When I open MSE, all types of several question comes up daily, for example, question related to probability, number theory, combinatorics and so on, have nothing to do with me and neither I can answer such type of questions. So how I can customize my settings so that when I open MSE, only those questions appears which are relevant to me?

There is similar question [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3453/how-to-see-questions-i-favourited) but seems not working for me.

Comment: Related: [Filtering by tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/filtering-by-tag)